# SQL persisting graph like data structures

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to figure out the best way to store graph data structures in an `SQL` database. After some research, it seems that I can store graph `Nodes` in a table and just create a join table with the `many-to-many` relationships between them which would represent the `edges` (or connections). That seems exactly what I was looking for, but now I want to introduce the users who own the nodes.

From the performance point of view, would it make sense to create a new join table `userNodes`, or just save users as `nodes` assuming that node is a generic structure? And what are the implications of storing everything in a single table?

Answer (score 0):

If you have individual attributes that should be stored on a per-node level, then those attributes should be in the `nodes` table.  That is what the table is for.

If the attributes are really a list, then you would want another table.  For instance, if multiple users could own a `node`, then one option would be a `userNodes` table.  However, as you describe the data, there is only one user per node.